# VS2017: “Cannot find the resource compiler DLL. Please make sure the path is correct.”

Tags: visual-c++-2017

I am using Visual Studio 2017. When I try to build a solution, I encounter this error:

> Cannot find the resource compiler DLL. Please make sure the path is correct.

I checked my system, and found that the v7.0, v8.0, v8.0A, v8.1A, and v10.0A SDKs are installed on my machine. I checked my project properties, and the default SDK is v8.0

Comment: can you share error screenshot ?

Answer (score 6):

Me too, i have only the "windows 10 sdk version 10.0.15063.0" installed, and solved after:

Copy rddll.dll from:
c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.15063.0\x86\rcdll.dll
to:
c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86\

ref link: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/43024/ide-cannot-find-the-resource-compiler-dll-rcdlldll.html

Just a temporary workaround, but it works.

**Edit:**

Run Visual Studio Installer from start menu, and click Update, after a while it's done, all thing worked.

it's doesn't need to copy file any more.

Comment: it is not enough to just copy that file - I tried using the repair in visual studio installer, but it still had the issue

Comment: in my case, it's Update, not repair

Comment: I ended up using visual studio installer to add the appropriate developer tools, and then asking it to update and then repair - took long time, but now it Works for me

Comment: Solved the problem by clicking Update

Answer (score 1):

you could copy from 
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.15063.0\x64\rc.exe 
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.15063.0\x64\rcdll.dll

to

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64\rc.exe 
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64\rcdll.dll

and copy from 
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.15063.0\x86\rc.exe 
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.15063.0\x86\rcdll.dll 
 to  
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86\rc.exe 
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86\rcdll.dll

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that Visual Studio cannot find the requested files.
You have to (re)install or repair the requested version through Visual Studio Installer.

You can reach that through Visual Studio menu bar -> Tools -> Get Tools and Features -> Individual Components -> find and tick the respective {version} tools to install and then click "Modify".

It should work after that. Best of luck.

Answer (score -1):

you can just simply change the compiler from resource compiler to C / C++ Compiler and you can do that by simply making a resource and you will face that error, after that right click the empty resource that have been generated and on the folder of resources right click the [nameofyourproject].rc and then choose properties and from item type change it to C / C++ Compiler and then delete that resource and create a new one and you will find it works fine with you.