# VS 2017: fatal error RC1015: cannot open include file 'winres.h'

Tags: mfc, visual-studio-2017, resource-editor

I just downloaded [Visual Studio 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/) and converted my dialog-based C++/MFC project with it (from Visual Studio 2008 SP1.) But then when I go to `Resources` it shows this error:

> fatal error RC1015: cannot open include file 'winres.h'

[image]

And idea how to fix this?

Comment: You need to configure Visual Studio so it knows where your Windows SDK is.  Sometimes the SDK itself has a tool.  Google it.

Comment: *"But then when I go to `Resources`"* - That needs a bit more detail. Are you referring to resources in your solution explorer? Some menu entry? Opening the resource script in a text editor? Opening a resource from the solution explorer?

Comment: @IInspectable: Yes, solution explorer. Although I did fix the issue by uninstalling VS2017 and downgrading to VS2015. That one was [too buggy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43315800/vs2017-cannot-find-the-resource-compiler-dll-please-make-sure-the-path-is-cor).

Comment: It's [probably still in beta](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/43024/ide-cannot-find-the-resource-compiler-dll-rcdlldll.html).

Answer (score 6):

I just also came across this issue. It seems my friend missed to push some VS 2017 meta file to the server. My quick solution is to change the Windows SDK version to match the Windows 10 OS version or below.
[image]

You can check your OS version from the cmd tool.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

[Jeff T. answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47936154/146513) is great if you have a single project.

If you have many projects in which you have to change the target Windows SDK (or if you want to make sure they all match), you'll probably prefer to use the **`Retarget Solution`** button found when right clicking on the **solution**:
[image: 1. Right click on solution, 2. "Retarget Solution"]

Then just select some Windows SDK version that you have installed, and apply it to all (or whatever) projects you need to change:
[image: 3. List of Windows SDK to choose and apply to all projects]

**That list of Windows SDK versions will probably show some that don't really work.** You might have to try.

Answer (score 1):

The missing files are located in two directories:
C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.15063.0\um
C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.15063.0\shared

Add the two paths to project properties (Project >> ...Properties >> Configuration Properties >> VC++ Directories >> Include Directories).

Answer (score 1):

You should install the framework MFC
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumbles onto this question is in the same boat as me (tried all of the above with no luck)..

I just created a fresh project and created a resource immediately (no issue) and then went ahead and readded all the code / libs that were needed. A bit annoying but I'm sure it was a mistake I made while configuring the project settings

Hopefully this helps someone out

Answer (score 0):

I my case, it was caused by wrong project configuration. Specifically `Property Pages -> VC++ Directories -> Include Directories` and there check **Inherit from parent or project defaults**.

Comment: I recommend this solution before manually adding a specific location.

Answer (score -1):

Probably [VS2017 fatal error RC1015 when attempting to add a new resource](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/54792/vs2017-fatal-error-rc1015-when-attempting-to-add-a.html). fellow also got this error with VS2017.